# solving $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{pq}}$=$\frac{\partial g}{\partial q}$ + $\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I was thinking about an integral and got it into the form:

$$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{pq}}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial q} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial p}$$

where $g$ is the integral as a function of $q$ and $p$.

I've not really done much on solving PDEs so was wondering if anyone could outline how you'd go about solving this.

I was thinking the symmetry between $q$ and $p$ is important, but really not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: Can you provide more information? For instance what kind of function $g$?

Comment: $g$ is the integral $g(p,q)$=$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(p\cos^2 x +q\sin^2 x)$ , then pde comes from the integral $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{pq}}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{p\cos^2x + q\sin^2x}$

Comment: The general solution to the PDE can be found with [the method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).  See the example given in wiki.

Comment: Thats great, thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial g(p,q)}{\partial q} + \frac{\partial g(p,q)}{\partial p}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{pq}}$$
The Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dp}{1}=\frac{dq}{1}=\frac{dg}{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{pq}}}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dp}{1}=\frac{dq}{1}$ :
$$p-q=c_1$$
A second charactristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dp}{1}=\frac{dg}{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{pq}}}$ with $q=p-c_1$ :

$dg=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{p(p-c_1)}}dp$

$g=\int \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{p(p-c_1)}}dp=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|p-\frac12 c_1+\sqrt{p(p-c_1)}\right|+c_2$
$$g-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|p-\frac12 c_1+\sqrt{p(p-c_1)}\right|=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ leads to :
$$\boxed{g(p,q)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{p+q}{2}+\sqrt{p\,q}\right|+F\left(p-q\right)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: Great, thanks for this